# Insert codeigniter insert but model don't return

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, mariadb

I have a very serious problem, basically my model performs the insert query by putting the tuple in the database but the model does not return any value. The code of the model is:

```
 $this->db->insert('magazzino_farmaci', $dati);
 return true;
```

In the model I perform a select and an update. I use mariaDb and xamp. Thanks for help.

Comment: `but the model does not return any value` mean doesnt return `true`? or you want last `inserted_id`?

Comment: As far as I can tell it doesn't return a value because you are saying return true so you are returning a boolean

Comment: @Bora 
I want the return that I have written to run. I want that I can return true

Comment: @ Robin Rijkeboer -> I want it to return true, but does not return anything, it will more true: (

Comment: Show us the complete function + the controller function.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
$query =$this->db->insert('magazzino_farmaci', $dati);
 if($query){
   return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter what happens, you're returning true. Even if the insert fails. Try this;

```
return $this->db->insert('magazzino_farmaci', $dati);
```

Comment: I want that I can return true, no matter what happens, the problem is that after the insert (which occurs in the database) the model does not return the value TRUE. This is the problem